# Partition a set of size $n$ into subsets of orders 1, 2, or 3

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am wondering if there is a formula for computing the number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ into subsets of orders 1, 2, or 3.

For example, a set of order 3 can be partitioned in 4 ways: $(\underline{1})(\underline{1})(\underline{1})$, $(\underline{1})(\underline{2})$, $(\underline{2})(\underline{1})$ and $(\underline{3})$.

Comment: are you sure that is ok? You seem to be asking that the two elements be contiguous.

Comment: Thanks for answering @JorgeFernándezHidalgo, it does not have to be an explicit formula, could be recursive too.

Comment: but you want the subsets to contain consecutive elements right? Otherwise you should also consider $\color{red} * \color{blue} * \color{red} *$

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we can let $f(n)$ be the number of sequences of positive integers $a_1,a_2\dots a_m$ with $a_1+a_2+\dots + a_m=n$ and $a_i\leq 3$.

We can do this recursively.

To do this separate the sequences that add to $n$ depending on the last summand.

There are $f(n-1)$ that end with $1$, there are $f(n-2)$ that end with $2$ and there are $f(n-3)$ that end with $3$.

We therefore obtain the recursion:

$f(1)=1,f(2)=2,f(3)=4, f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)+f(n-3)$ for $n\geq 4$

Comment: If you want a $\mathcal O\log(n)$ algorithm you can use binary exponentiation on the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$